# <video> not supported on iPhone devices?

Tags: android, html, ios, video, media

I come today with a 'fairly easy' question around using video.

I have used this before and it seems to be working on Android devices. However, I just recently realised that the same video won't work on any Apple device.

My initial thought was around the video format (which is currently MP4), so I added a 'webm' back-up. MP4 should be enough, but I just wanted to give it a try (unsuccessfully)

Am I missing something? Do I need an specific format to be able to display a video on Apple devices?

```html
<video class="intro-header-mobile" playsinline autoplay loop muted preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%">
  <source src="/medias/custom-content/projects/2021/Own-brand-hub/e0821_Ownbrand_mob_v2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/medias/custom-content/projects/2021/Own-brand-hub/e0821_Ownbrand_mob_v2.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Thank you everyone!

Diana

Comment: Webm are not currently supported on iPhones. MP4 usually work but some might not depending on how they were encoded. If you have a Mac computer then I would advice to check if the mp4 file plays in QuickTime player on Mac. If not then probably it uses some encoding that is not supported also on iPhone. Also if you have an iPhone you can try to open this mp4 file directly in Safari (put mp4 url in address bar) and check if it plays there.

Comment: Hello @LeszekSzary I have tried this, and even added a Ogg version of the video too. I have checked on iPad and it won't work. It should support mp4, but it isn't :O

Comment: Hello, if it does not play in Safari on iPad even if you paste direct link to mp4 file in address bar then this mp4 must be encoded with some codec that is not supported on iOS and probably it will not work. I think this mp4 would have to be reencoded with different settings with tool such as ffmpeg and only then you will be able to make it work on iOS.